# How does a neural network work with correlated image data

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to TensorFlow and deep learning.  I am trying to create a fully connected neural network for image processing. I am somewhat confused.

We have an image, say 28x28 pixels.  This will have 784 inputs to the NN. For non-correlated inputs, this is fine, but image pixels are generally correlated. For instance, consider a picture of a cow's eye.  How can a neural network understand this when we have all pixels lined up in an array for a fully-connected network.  How does it determine the correlation?

Comment: the network doesn't essentially "assumes" only numbers that are "next" to each other on the input vector should be considered correlated. being fully connected means there is no importance to the "order" in which the input appears as long as it is consistent. (tldr - the net can find connections even with the pixels are lined up)

Comment: A convolutional neural network does exactly that, a fully connected network cannot find such correlations by itself.

Comment: Any sufficiently large neural net (assuming adequate non-linearities) can essentially learn the correlations, although really it's learning merely an adequate heuristic.  However, a fully-connected neural network is throwing away massive amounts of resources filtering out noise related to random relationships between distant pixels of the image.  This is precisely what the CNN (convolutional neural network) addresses.  I would therefore recommend researching CNNs once you have an adequate handle on the more general machine learning basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please research some tutorials on CNN (Convolutional Neural Network); [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) is a starting point for you.  A fully connected layer of a NN surrenders *all* of the correlation information it might have had with the input.  Structurally, it implements the principle that the inputs are statistically independent.

Alternately, a convolution layer depends upon the physical organization of the inputs (such as pixel adjacency), using that to find simple combinations (convolutions) of feature form one layer to another.

Bottom line: your NN doesn't find the correlation: the topology is wrong, and cannot do the job you want.

---

Also, please note that a layered network consisting of fully-connected neurons with linear weight combinations, is *not* **deep learning**.  Deep learning has at least one hidden layer, a topology which fosters "understanding" of intermediate structures.  A purely linear, fully-connected layering provides no such hidden layers.  Even if you program hidden layers, the outputs remain a simple linear combination of the inputs.

Deep learning requires some other discrimination, such as convolutions, pooling, rectification, or other non-linear combinations.

Comment: Why are there negative replies? I hope I get it from the answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it into peaces to understand the intuition behind NN learning to predict.

to predict a class of given image we have to find a correlation or direct link between once of it is input values to the class. we can think about finding one pixel can tell us this image belongs to this class. which is impossible so what we have to do is build up more complex function or let's call complex features. which will help us to find to generate a correlated data to the wanted class.

To make it simpler imagine you want to build AND function (p and q), OR function (p or q) in the both cases there is a direct link between the input and the output. in and function if there 0 in the input the output always zero. so what if we want to xor function (p xor q) there is no direct link between the input and the output. the answer is to build first layer of classifying AND and OR then by a second layer taking the result of the first layer we can build the function and classify the XOR function 
(p xor q) = (p or q) and not (p and q)

By applying this method on Multi-layer NN you'll have the same result. but then you'll have to deal with huge amount of parameters. one solution to avoid this is to extract representative, variance and uncorrelated features between images and correlated with their class from the images and feed the to the Network. you can look for image features extraction on the web.

this is a small explanation for how to see the link between images and their classes and how NN work to classify them. you need to understand NN concept and then you can go to read about Deep-learning.